# Missing return statement due to If condition

Tags: java

So I have the following function:

```
int digitsum(int n){
    int s = n;
    if(n < 10) 
        return s;     
    while(s > 0){
        n = s + n % 10;
        s = n / 10;
    }
    digitsum(n);
}
```

I want to take a number and get the sum of its digits and I want to keep doing that until I end up with a single digit number. From what I can understand here, the `if` statement is causing an error during compilation, it says `missing return statement` and highlights the last `}` .

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Terrible code formatting will only make folks not want to read your code. I've tried to fix it for you, but in the future, please do this yourself. Also, where does your method return if the if condition is false?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the edit, will keep in mind. I want the computer to just re call the function.

Comment: That won't work. Every method that is declared to return something **must** return something (with a few "exceptions" that we won't go into here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in non-void function , every function call must trace to a return statement and as java says

> Every execution path in a function must lead to a RETURN statement

so add this `return digitsum(n);`

according to this rule in java , if this condition is `if(n < 10)` `false` then there is no further `return` statement exists so either there should be a default `return` statement or there should be some other `return` statement in conditional `else` case.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(n<10) return s;
```

When n >= 10, what is the return value?

Comment: Just want the function to be re-called. Thanks for checking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function return type is `int` so it must return `int` value in **every case**. You can add `return 0` or you can make it `void`.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is declared as void, you don't have to use the return statement (you can use System.out.Println for example), but if you declared the method as int, then you have to return an int.